# export 3d plot from Mathematica into MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 3d, wolfram-mathematica, plot, export

I am using Mathematica to produce some 3d plots but since the files are huge I can't simply manipulate the 3d graphs in Mathematica, so I decided to export them into MATLAB and work with the graphs there. I did:

```
Export["filename.eps",exp]
```

but I could not open the 3d graph in MATLAB.

Where am I wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be expecting Matlab to read an EPS file written by Mathematica and to further manipulate it.  Since an EPS (Encapsulated PostScript) file will contain only a 2D projection of your 3D plot, one intended for printing, even if Matlab will read and display an EPS file it isn't going to be able to do anything with the 3rd dimension which isn't directly represented in the file. I think this is where you are going wrong.

Surely what you ought to be doing is exporting the datasets from Mathematica and importing them into Matlab ?  If so, edit your question and provide some more details about your datasets and the code you've written so far.

I'm a little surprised that you expect Matlab to be able to display large datasets with significantly more performance than Mathematica, it's not something I've noticed but then it's  not something I've looked closely into.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer.I have solved a PDE using NDSolve in Mma and I am going to plot3D my function in Matlab.I have a large data set and since I am kind of new to Mma I don't know how I can export my data set into a Matlab file and then plot it using Matlab.